# Json deserialization - System.Collections.Generic.List error

Tags: c#, json, jsonresponse

I got http result in JSON like that

```json
{
   "success":true,
   "message":[
      
   ],
   "conversationList":[
      "dd184c5a-7eb7-4e98-b588-975853c51b18",
      "a3c25d14-d0d5-4e79-928b-1123fe1ba587",
      "8c5e2869-43f8-4555-9afd-3b1e679d5ed0",
      "843dcbd4-33fc-487f-9971-7fd80ff378c4",
      "62dcee64-aeb6-448d-9422-c6b94a22aa02",
      "409a8da6-bf32-4dee-923c-213a9971283c"
   ]
}
```

I make classes like that:

```
public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public List<object> message { get; set; }
    public List<string> conversationList { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialization like this:

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(result);
```

Then I got this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp9.Root]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'success', line 1, position 11.'

I want to use foreach on this and get all `conversationList`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Do you recieve this exact JSON? if so, then change `List<Root>` to `Root`

Comment: Change `var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(result);` to `var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);`

Comment: When I use this I get output: "ConsoleApp9.Root"

Comment: Are you calling `.ToString()` on `deserializedJson`? What code do you have that produces that output? We need more details.

Comment: This output I get from external API as http result. I calling `deserializedJson` and I try `deserializedJson.ToString()` result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you don' t have  a list in your root. Use this

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
```

Comment: When I use this I get output: "ConsoleApp9.Root"

Comment: I tested json you posted in Visual Studio. Everything is working properly. How you got json you posted?

Comment: This output I get from external API as http result.

Comment: @encoder93x if you have an error, it means that you have a different output. Could you check again pls?

Comment: Not error, output from deserializedJson = "ConsoleApp9.Root", should be "dd184c5a-7eb7-4e98-b588-975853c51b18"...

Comment: @encoder93x   I am talking about your api response  json string , I know what should deserialization  result.

Comment: My HTTP result from external API is `{
   "success":true,
   "message":[
      
   ],
   "conversationList":[
      "dd184c5a-7eb7-4e98-b588-975853c51b18",
      "a3c25d14-d0d5-4e79-928b-1123fe1ba587",
      "8c5e2869-43f8-4555-9afd-3b1e679d5ed0",
      "843dcbd4-33fc-487f-9971-7fd80ff378c4",
      "62dcee64-aeb6-448d-9422-c6b94a22aa02",
      "409a8da6-bf32-4dee-923c-213a9971283c"
   ]
}`